# Haskell - Checking If Any String In List is In A String

Tags: haskell

I am looking for the reverse of this essentially, and am going out of my mind.

Something that reverses the arguments of the below to check of any element of a list is in a string.

Instead of:
`any (isInfixOf "Hask") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]`

I need:
`any (isInfixOf ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]) "I am new to"`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write this with a lambda expression as:

```
any (\x -> isInfixOf x "I am new to") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]
```

Here `x` is thus the item in the list for which we call `isInfixOf x "I am new to"`. This thus means that if one such element in the list is the infix of `"I am new to"`, it will return `True`, otherwise it will return `False`.

You can also make use of [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip):

```
any (flip isInfixOf "I am new to") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]
```

or with an [*operator section* [Haskell-wiki]](http://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator):

```
any (`isInfixOf` "I am new to") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]
```

Comment: Thanks so much - flip is a lifesaver.